# I am trying a different approach in python

Tags: python

The goal of my code is to ask for the the data input and the target in a dictionary format. The input is the word and the target is the definition and I want to return the output which is the target or the definition. I am trying a different approach, can you help me?

```
def search(input, target):
    data_words = []
    for x in input:
        data_words += [x[0].lower()]
    if target.lower() not in data_words:
        return "Word does not exist"
    else:
        index = data_words.index(target.lower())
        return (input[index][-1])
```

Comment: You are getting downvoted because we don't know what to help you with? Try asking a proper question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask?msclkid=cf40da5ec63211ecb0f31c2fd8bb8c3a

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, you're trying to get definitons of words. Such as:

Definition of apple: the round fruit of a tree of the rose family, which typically has thin green or red skin and crisp flesh.

You can create a dict and add your target's (in this case apple) and definitions into that dict.

First you should install `nltk` package.

Simply, run `pip install nltk` on your terminal.

Here's the code:

```
# Use nltk to tokenize words
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

# Create your definitions dictionary
dictionary = {'apple': 'the round fruit of a tree of the rose family, which typically has thin green or red skin and crisp flesh.',
            'banana': 'a long curved fruit which grows in clusters and has soft pulpy flesh and yellow skin when ripe.'}

def search(sentence):
    sentence = sentence.lower()
    tokenize = word_tokenize(sentence)
    for i in tokenize:
        if i in dictionary:
            print(f"The definition of {i} is:", dictionary[i])

getDefinition = input("The word that you want to see it's definiton: ")
search(getDefinition)
```